# Can't parse XML (from web) using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to work with small `XML` files sent from web and parse few attributes from them. How would I approach this in `JSoup`? I know it's not `XML` Parser but `HTML` one but it supports `XML` too and I don't have to build any Handlers, BuildFactories and such as I would have to in `DOM`, `SAX` etc.

Here is example xml: [LINK](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Private%20Ryan&y=&plot=short&r=xml) I can't paste it here because it exits the code tag after every line - if someone can fix that I would be grateful.

And here is my piece of code::

```
String xml = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Private%20Ryan&y=&plot=short&r=xml";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
// want to select first occurrence of genre tag though there is only one it 
// doesn't work without .first() - but it doesn't parse it
Element genreFromXml = doc.select("genre").first();
String genre = genreFromXml.text();
System.out.println(genre);
```

It results in NPE at:

```
String genre = genreFromXml.text();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. You provide a `String` representation of an `URL` while an `XML` content is expected, you should rather use the method [`parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri, Parser parser)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.parser.Parser-) instead to parse your XML as an input stream.
2. There is no element `genre` in your `XML`, `genre` is an attribute of the element `movie`.

Here is how your code should look like:

```
String url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Private%20Ryan&y=&plot=short&r=xml";
// Parse the doc using an XML parser
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
// Select the first element "movie"
Element movieFromXml = doc.select("movie").first();
// Get its attribute "genre"
String genre = movieFromXml.attr("genre");
// Print the result
System.out.println(genre);
```

**Output:**

```
Drama, War
```

Comment: I have to handle Malformed and IO Exceptions from URL right? My IDE says I do, but want to check with you.

Comment: Yes you need to deal with the exception, you could simply throw it

Comment: Do you know how could I access just the first word in genre without working on a String using array to pick only 'Drama'? Because very often movies on IMDB have many genres assigned and I need only one.

Comment: apart manipulating the `String` like what you describe for example, I have no idea, IMHO it is the only way

Comment: Alright, did that with .split and then accessing right index. Thank you for your help!